# Hacer una fórmula a partir de vectores, con Javascript

Tags: javascript

Necesito crear ecuaciones a partir de vectores dados, por ejemplo:

```
const variables = ["Var1", "Var2", "Var3"];

const coeficiente= [3.56, -.65, 354.625];
const operacion_intermedio = ['+', '-', null]
const operandos = ['*', '+', '/'];
```

Y que me dé un string como resultado:

```
~'(var1*3.56)+(Var2*-.65)-(var3/354.625)'
```

Es decir, que la operación sea así: `(variables*coeficiente*operandos)+operacion_intermedio` y que lo haga por el tamaño del vector.

¿Es posible algo así?

Comment: Sí, es posible. ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: @PabloLozano He intentado métodos como join y concat, sin embargo, no me permite combinar los distintos tipos de arrays, ya que algunos son de tipo número y otros string. He estado intentando también incluso tokenizar, sin embargo, creo que no me funciona para el caso que quisiera resolver.

Comment: Puedes recorrer uno de los arrays e ir concatenando cada posición de cada array.